# Equivalent of glove.6b.100d.txt pour nlp classification for french vocabulary

Tags: stanford-nlp

My dataset is in french. I am wondering if there is an equivalent of french embedding similar as glove.6b.100d.txt ?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Glove doesn't have word embedding for any other language than English.

But you may rely on [Spacy](https://spacy.io) supports french. See their trained models for french languages here: https://spacy.io/models/fr